# Is it possible to crack ASCII 2 HEX - JavaScript Encryptor

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

I'm developing a commercial software project that has some sensitive JavaScript code.

I know that's impossible to prevent anyone from seeing my code, so I looked into ways to make it more difficult to do so, and I found [this page](http://utenti.multimania.it/ascii2hex/) witch looks promising, as it locks the JavaScript from being accessed from any other page/URL.

So my question is how secure is this solution?

Feel free to suggest any other ways to "hide" the JavaScript code.

Comment: That page only looks promissing in that it looks like a hoax in my definition. When I looked at it, it was full of "spam" and "hoax" like adverts. You must have visited with some kind of ad-blocker to take that page seriously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not, it's already downloaded to the users machine, they can look at it in their script debugger, there's nothing you can do to prevent someone from looking at your code, the best you can do is obfuscate it but that only deters the casual thieves.

Also if you're putting sensitive code on the client side then you may want to refactor your architecture.

Answer (score 3):

whatever goes to the client side will never be secure, whether encrypted or not (since the client code - jscript - will need to decode it and that's easy to hack-into)

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be "not very secure" – at some point you need to feed the JavaScript in unencrypted (or rather unencoded) form to the browser's JS engine, which is where an attacker can access it.

My suggestion on hiding sensitive code is to not send it to users in the first place.

I can't actually get the thing to work, but looking at their (not "encrypted") page source, the "decryption" method is an `eval(unescape("the result of some bizarre maths on the hex values"))`. Copy-pasting what's inside the `eval()` into a JS console would probably give you your original code back.

Comment: The really disconcerting  thing is that this is already v1.2 - didn't anyone tell these poor sods that they're wasting their time?

Comment: @Pointy: Well, to their credit, it seems they don't make it /that/ easy. It returns some JS code that does some maths on more strings of escaped hex values, then unescapes and evals those, possibly with several levels of nesting this nonsense. Still nothing that can't be broken with some dilligence applied of course.

Answer (score 0):

This obfuscator (**ASCII 2 HEX v1.2 (JavaScript Encryptor)**) can give some difficulties in reading your code (obviously JavaScript code cannot be hidden). It won't run directly on the website, you have to download the source code and save it to a "dummy.html" file:

http://js-x.com/page/javascripts__example.html?view=1109

For example, "alert('Hello world!')" would return this code:

```
<Script Language=Javascript>
<!--
eval(unescape('%68%35%3D%30%3B%68%30%3D%27%%36%44%%36%35%%36%45%%37%34%%32%45%%35%35%%35%32%%34%43%%33%42%27%3B%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%68%31%35%28%68%31%31%29%7B%68%38%3D%4D%61%74%68%2E%72%6F%75%6E%64%28%68%31%31%2F%34%30%39%36%2D%2E%35%29%3B%68%31%33%3D%68%31%31%2D%68%38%2A%34%30%39%36%3B%68%39%3D%4D%61%74%68%2E%72%6F%75%6E%64%28%68%31%33%2F%32%35%36%2D%2E%35%29%3B%68%31%34%3D%68%31%33%2D%68%39%2A%32%35%36%3B%68%31%30%3D%4D%61%74%68%2E%72%6F%75%6E%64%28%68%31%34%2F%31%36%2D%2E%35%29%3B%68%31%36%3D%68%31%34%2D%68%31%30%2A%31%36%3B%72%65%74%75%72%6E%28%27%27%2B%68%31%39%28%68%31%30%29%2B%68%31%39%28%68%31%36%29%29%3B%7D%68%32%3D%27%%30%39%%31%38%%31%31%%30%32%%34%45%%30%37%%30%38%%33%42%%31%31%%30%44%%30%46%%30%34%%34%46%%30%31%%30%41%%30%30%%30%41%%30%38%%34%45%%35%30%%30%37%27%3B%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%68%31%39%28%68%32%31%29%7B%69%66%28%68%32%31%3C%31%30%29%72%65%74%75%72%6E%20%68%32%31%3B%65%6C%73%65%20%72%65%74%75%72%6E%20%53%74%72%69%6E%67%2E%66%72%6F%6D%43%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%28%68%32%31%2B%35%35%29%3B%7D%68%34%3D%27%27%3B%68%37%3D%27%%36%38%%33%36%%33%44%%36%34%%36%46%%36%33%%37%35%27%3B%68%31%3D%68%32%2E%73%70%6C%69%74%28%27%%27%29%3B%65%76%61%6C%28%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%68%37%2B%68%30%29%29%3B%68%31%37%3D%27%%36%35%%37%36%%36%31%%36%43%%32%38%%37%35%%36%45%%36%35%%37%33%%36%33%%36%31%%37%30%%36%35%%32%38%%36%38%%33%34%%32%39%%32%39%27%3B%66%6F%72%28%68%33%3D%31%3B%68%33%3C%68%31%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%3B%68%33%2B%2B%29%7B%68%34%2B%3D%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%27%%27%2B%68%31%35%28%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%27%%27%2B%68%31%5B%68%33%5D%29%2E%63%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%41%74%28%30%29%5E%68%36%2E%63%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%41%74%28%68%35%29%29%29%3B%68%35%2B%2B%3B%69%66%28%68%35%3D%3D%68%36%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%29%68%35%3D%30%3B%7D%3B%65%76%61%6C%28%75%6E%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%68%31%37%29%29'));
//-->
</Script>
```